# Aspose Cells - Preserver the leading zeros in a CSV

Tags: c#, aspose-cells

I am using Aspose cells for a pretty simple report. The problem is that I have a few fields that have leading zeros.  When opened in CSV, I do not see the leading zeros.  If I look at the text, I can see the zeros

Any ideas how to keep the leading zeros

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont feel this is the perfect solution, but I was able to get the results I wanted. Basically formatted the column with string.Format("=\"{0}\"", content.account_no));  But I had to interate through the rows

```
int curretCol = System.Array.FindIndex<string>(clmAry, (string r) => r.ToString() == "account_no");
                int currentrow = 1;

                foreach (GLSearchDC content in GLList)
                {
                    Cell cell = worksheet.Cells[CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(currentrow++, curretCol)];

                        cell.PutValue(string.Format("=\"{0}\"", content.Account_No));
                    content.account_no));
                }
```

Comment: Yes, your solution is also good and serve the purpose. Best regards, Shakeel.